# SOAP как добавить атрибут к тегу?

Tags: php, soap

Вот так формирую запрос:

```
try {
    $result = $client->PostalOrderEventsForMail([
        'AuthorizationHeader' =>[
            'login'=>'noulwvHotQmxCg',
            'password' => 'XBHjxRnaQ32Q',

        ],
            'PostalOrderEventsForMailInput'=>[
                'Barcode'=>'111111',
                'Language'=>'RUS'
            ]
]
    );
//    $client->__getLastRequest();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Получилось сформировать такой запрос:

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
              xmlns:ns1="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory/data"
              xmlns:ns2="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory">
    <env:Body>
        <ns2:PostalOrderEventsForMail>
            <ns1:AuthorizationHeader>
                <ns1:login>Логин</ns1:login>
                <ns1:password>Пароль</ns1:password>
            </ns1:AuthorizationHeader>
        </ns2:PostalOrderEventsForMail>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

В документах написано что вот так должна выглядеть строка:

```
 <data:AuthorizationHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
```

Как сформировать такую строку?(добавить атрибут)

Comment: Какой класс у переменной `$client`? Покажите, что происходит с массивом, который вы передаете в `PostalOrderEventsForMail`